# How to set current url so relative links resolve correctly when injecting custom html in puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I am trying to create a new page and manually set its content. Because the url of a blank page with injected code is still about:blank, all of the relative links on the page are broken. Is there a way to set the url of the page without actually navigating to that url via goto?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two options:

1. Create a function to turn a relative path into a `file://` URL.
2. Run a simple server. I wrote a post about that [on my blog](https://www.hardkoded.com/blogs/implementing-simple-server)

Comment: Maybe also [`<base>`: The Document Base URL element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)? Or it cannot be used with `file://` URLs?